# mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'lfc_site'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, centos, mariadb, plesk

I am switching my hosting platform from cPanel to Plesk and seem to be having some issues with a script on one of my sites. The main site is running on the latest version of Joomla and makes it's database connection with no errors. I have an external script that I run on a cron job however that does not seem to connect. I get this error:

```
mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'lfc_site'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have to assume that it has to do with my connection class so I will post it here:

1. I have a cofig.ini that contains the DB login credentials.

   [database]
   username = database_user
   password = ******
   dbname = database_name

then my connection class is this:

```
<?php
//Database connection class
class Db {
  protected static $connection;
  public function connect() {    
    if(!isset(self::$connection)) {
      global $config;
      self::$connection = new mysqli('localhost:3306',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
    }
    if(self::$connection === false) {
      return false;
    }
    return self::$connection;
  }
  public function query($query) {
    $connection = $this -> connect();
    $result = $connection -> query($query);
    return $result;
  }
  public function select($query) {
    $rows = array();
    $result = $this -> query($query);
    if($result === false) {
        return false;
    }
    while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
  }
  public function error() {
    $connection = $this -> connect();
    return $connection -> error;
  }
  public function quote($value) {
    $connection = $this -> connect();
    return "'" . $connection -> real_escape_string($value) . "'";
  }
}
?>
```

and then finally my script runs the query as such....

```
<?php
require_once('/var/www/vhosts/user/httpdocs/db.php');
$config = parse_ini_file('/var/www/vhosts/user/httpdocs/config.ini');

$db = new Db();
$rows = $db -> select('
    SELECT * 
    FROM milestones 
    WHERE status != "arrived" 
    AND departure_time BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR) 
    AND (NOW() + INTERVAL 12 HOUR) 
    AND type = "4"
');

?>
```

I am guessing that maybe there is a module not enabled that is prohibiting this script from establishing a connection properly, as like I said, the Joomla script seems to connect without issue using the exact same credentials?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "external script"?

By the output you gave I assume it is located on the same machine as the Joomla installation.

The problem most likely doesn't lie with your credentials (if they work for Joomla and you have double-checked them) but with the hostname you provide or a server configuration or MariaDB user (lfc_site) permissions.

You can try to change `localhost` in your code to `127.0.0.1` and see if it makes any difference.

If not, please SSH into your server and provide output of

1. `plesk db` and then `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'lfc_site';`
2. and `grep bind /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

for further investigations.